# Where are the WeChat chat logs stored?

Tags: backup, macbook, logging, chat

I'd like to back up my WeChat chat logs, so I tried backing the chat logs up to my computer using the OS X WeChat application. It backed up successfully, but I can't find the chat logs anywhere. I checked in package contents in the application folder and found nothing. Ideally I'd find a text file or something similar with all the chat contents that I could back up to Google Drive myself, because I don't want to put 100% trust in these applications to back up the chat onto my computer (which is only local to begin with, I'd prefer something cloud based), and I'd like to send the chat file to my friend who lost their chat with me.

Are there any solutions to this?

Phone is an Android, computer is on OS X High Sierra.

Answer (score 8):

I've dug around and found what probably is the folder where the backup is stored:

```
/Users/USERNAME/Library/Containers/com.tencent.xinWeChat/Data/Library/Application Support/com.tencent.xinWeChat/2.0b4.0.9/Backup/
```

If you can't find the Library folder, press "Go" on the menu bar and while pressing "Alt", Library should be visible.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Even if you can locate the file, the file is encoded with some algorithm (i.e. it's not plain text)

Comment: **UPDATE** The backup file consists of 2 encrypted SQLite DB for each backup, and 1 SQLite DB for indexing. Checked with SQLite DB browser.

Comment: /Users/<username>/Library/Containers/
"WeChat" or "com.tencent.xinWeChat"
/Data/Library/Application Support/com.tencent.xinWeChat/2.0b4.0.9/Backup/...

Also not detected as SQLite dbs `Backup.db`, `Backup.db-backup`, or `BAK_0_TEXT`, or app requires password to open them...