# Where is stored the backups of WeChat?

Tags: windows, backup, android, ios, chat

I have an Android device with some conversations of WeChat. I would like to do a backup of these conversations, so I am using the Windows 10 application of WeChat, it seems that it is the way to do the backup.

The problem is that I don't know where is the backups stored.

I have read this question: [Where are the WeChat chat logs stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/1270471/where-are-the-wechat-chat-logs-stored), but searching for this folder or database `.db` or any other of the files that are said in this answer, I can´t find it.

I am using version 2.6.3.300 of WeChat in Windows.

Thanks.

EDIT: I added the screen of settings. Because I don't have the backup settings available.

My screens:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**** First of all, in Wechat, 'Backup' is not exactly the same as 'Save Wechat History' in Settings (that's another story. I'm supplementing this chat for 'Backup' only.*

The backups are not on the PC because you have not transferred them there (yet).
Here is how to transfer them to the PC (according to the documentation):

- Open WeChat on your PC. The app is found on http://www.wechat.com/en/
- Click ☰ at the bottom-left corner of the WeChat window
- Click **Backup and Restore**, and the appropriate screen will appear

**At the bottom of this screen, there's an option 'Manage Backup Files'**

[image]

**If you click on it, another dialogue box appears, and you'll see the path of the Backup Directory at the top. That's the default directory. I've changed mine to a different one.**

[image]

- Open WeChat on your phone while connected to the same WiFi network as the PC
- Click **Back up on PC** on the computer. The "Back up chat history to the computer" screen will appear on the phone
- Tap *Backup All* on the phone and wait for the backup to complete.
  If you'd prefer to select specific chats instead, tap *Select Chat History*,
  tap the chats to back up, then tap *Backup*.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I told I used the windows 10 application to do the backup, I followed this steps, but when the backup is finished, where could I find the backup files? I guess that when the backup is finished, is stored in the PC.

Comment: You might find them in the folder `C:\Users\USERNAME\Documents\WeChat Files`. Otherwise you can probably find the folder in the WeChat Settings.

Comment: I don't have wechat folder un my drive, neither in documents, and in we chat settings, there is no way to set or see the backup folder.

Comment: According to [this tutorial](https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-back-up-and-free-up-wechat-data-to-your-computer) it should have been visible in the backup process or after.

Answer (score 3):

For the original non-UWP version from the Windows Store, it is stored in:

```
C:\Users\username1\AppData\Local\Packages\TencentWeChatLimited.forWindows10_sdtnhv12zgd7a\LocalCache\Roaming\Tencent\WeChatAppStore\WeChatAppStore Files\username2\BackupFiles
```

username1 is your Windows account and username2 is your WeChat account name. Fairly easy finding it thanks to "Everything" by voidtools. Don't know if it's unique or different after "TencentWeChatLimited.forWindows10_", but this is the path on my Windows 10 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 2):

I found the path on my Windows 10 x64 for [WeChat from Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4SLX7) which is:

```
C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\TencentWeChatLimited.forWindows10_sdtnhv12zgd7a\LocalCache\Roaming\Tencent\WeChatAppStore\WeChatAppStore Files\USERNAME\BackupFiles\
```

PS:

1. You may need to check the "Hidden items" under the View tab of the File Explorer to allow you can see the `AppData` folder with Hidden Attributes.
2. Replace `USER` with your Windows account.
3. Replace `USERNAME` with your WeChat account.